# ElasticSearch Version Upgrade in AWS EKS using Helm Charts [7.17.3 -> 8.5.1]

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-eks, elasticsearch-8

Have deployed **ElasticSearch** version **7.17.3** in **AWS EKS** using helm chart https://github.com/elastic/helm-charts.

My goal is to upgrade my ES to the latest version **8.5.1** using helm chart. I followed the steps mentioned in **Upgrade Assistant** in ES **[Management -> Stack Management -> Upgrade Assistant]**.

In upgrade assistant, I made sure all the check points are fixed and good to be migrated. But when I try to migrate, I am unable to see any solution for upgrading using helm chart.

If I either preform helm upgrade using the new helm-chart [`helm upgrade --install elastic elastic/elasticsearch --version 8.5.1 -n elasticsearch`] or directly change the image version from **7.17.3 to 8.5.1** in **existing deployment**, I end up with errors and my ES pod isn't up and running.

Is there any proper documentation or reference that can be used for **ES version** upgrade using **helm charts**.